# Time-based token distribution in smart contract

Tags: timestamp, time

Say I have a smart contract for exchanging 6 `Token_A` with 6 `Token_B` with an additional time condition when only 1 exchange can happen every 1 month (we don't care about `msg.sender` here. we can assume all actions can be done by one address):

> In day 0, owner will trigger `claim` function that moves 1 `Token_A`
> to their address and 1 `Token_B` to someone else's address.
>
> In day 6, if owner triggers `claim` function, the request will be
> rejected.
>
> In day 30, owner can trigger `claim` for another token exchange and so
> on.

The simple solution I can think of is to create a list of timestamps and fill it with 6 timestamps (starting from creation of contract) and one pointer. Every time a claim request comes in, we can compare `timestamp[pointer]` with `block.timestamp` and increment pointer if this is a valid claim.

Though this might work for one user, this is going to become tricky if we have more than only one user (say we have a list of whitelisted users - timestamp list will be same for all but we will need multiple pointers for each user).

Any better solution for this problem?

Answer (score 1):

These are the solutions i came up with

- Off-Chain Managing and toggling useAvailableToClaim boolean mapping to address of the user, this solves the most risky part of managing users time and also allowing people to claim from the smart contract.
- Using a Factory Method , each user gets their own smart contract and has the solution you have suggested. The token supply state is managed on the factory smart contract and it is distributed from the factory smart contract if needed

Comment: The first approach is interesting but the Owner will need to pay the gas fee every time they want to make the function available for a user. For the second approach, it will at too much complexity in case the number of users are significant. thanks for the suggestions!